# Flutter - sharedpreferences getString method

Tags: flutter, sharedpreferences, getstring

I successfuly saved a string to sharedpreferences. But, I dont understand how to getString and use this a parameter llike below code.

My getstring method;

```
Future<String> getString(String param) async {
SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
return prefs.getString(param) ?? 'lang';
```

I try to send a string with fetchApps method. This string should comes from sharedpreferences getString method.

```
return FutureBuilder<List<Apps>>(
        future: fetchApps(getString('lang')),
        builder: (c, s) {
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your getString function is a `Future` You should use await in your `getString('lang')` like this:

```
return FutureBuilder<List<Apps>>(
        future: fetchApps(await getString('lang')),
        builder: (c, s) {
```

Comment: await getString('lang') and The argument type 'Future<String>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'.

Comment: then, maybe u assign it to something else first?
```final bla = await getString('lang')``` before u passed it to your fetchApps ```fetchApps(bla)```

Comment: I did but still giving error. The await expression can only be used in an async function.
Try marking the function body with either 'async' or 'async*

Comment: yes, you need to make your function as async

```yourFunction async {
final bla = await getString('lang')
}
```

Comment: Ok, i got it. I applied your reply in my fetchApps method. It works.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61170032/flutter-scrollcontroller-attached-to-multiple-scroll-views